# Research into expert status

Tags: user-expectation

I understand that UX is a temporal concept. I can design an interface great for adoptability but this might be sub optimal for experts. A good example would be command line interfaces for developers.

Are there any research / reference points which look at when a user transitions to an expert status?

Comment: Have you found any results on your own? I imagine expert-ness depends so much on the particular domain and app you're looking at that research on anything will be unusable elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the eternal struggles of interaction design is how to address the needs of both beginning users and expert users within a single interface. It's good to remember that most users do not fall in the beginner or expert segment, but rather the intermediate. New users tend to quickly learn enough to be considered intermediate, while it takes a great deal of time to become proficient enough to become an expert.

Becoming an expert correlates with time spent using the tool. In some specialized products, it is good to optimize the user experience mainly for experts. They'll be using the UI every single day. At some point, even if they aren't actively trying, they'll become more familiar with the interface. Development tools often fall into this category, as you mentioned.

So, to answer the question; when does someone 'graduate' from beginner to expert? That's hard to tell, and it depends on your users. Generally, tools for professionals tends to have people become experts quickly, as their job relies on their proficiency. But something someone uses once a month will rarely see experts, but a lot of beginners and intermediates. One thing is for certain; your UI has to accommodate both the beginner and the expert, without one being compromised by the needs of the other.

The book 'About face', has a lot of information about the subject. Highly recommended.